# What is the difference between long and regular polling?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Over here, *every 30 seconds*, I make an AJAX call updating my db.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);
    }, dataType: "json"});
}, 30000);
```

Another side question - what would be the downside if the server takes more than 30 seconds to respond? The call would send another request while call #1 is being updated - updating the db to the latest value.

Long Polling

```
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);

    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
})();
```

AJAX call is sent, invokes itself every 30 seconds, and once the call is complete it calls itself again. While it looks more synchronous, what if we send a call, hit the end of 30 seconds (while I'm waiting for first call to come back)?

Now we have that same "issue" we had in the first one. Issue in speech marks because I don't really see an issue with sending an AJAX request while I'm waiting for a response from a preceding one.

Thanks! Let me know if this question wasn't clear.

Comment: The first method is very frowned upon, for the exact reason you mention: *if the server takes more than 30 seconds to respond* - you should always wait for a response, else you risk requests piling up with no order of response guarantee

Comment: If the second one times out, it doesn't look like it would be called again

Comment: i would say perhaps add a timestamp token of sorts, so if a prior call times out (or takes longer but still comes back) you always have the most recent. Also only update on valid responses - EDIT : This also feels less like a stack question and more like a "Code Review" question

Comment: @ExplosionPills I just looked up the timeout parameter, so if a request is sent, and then we hit timeout, the request is discarded? And in this case, the end-to-end AJAX request ceast to continue, correct?

Comment: @tymeJV Sorry but could you tell me bad things that could happen due to piled up requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);
    }, dataType: "json"});
}, 30000);
```

Is that you're not setting a timeout on the AJAX request itself. This leaves it undefined and as such you could have a build-up of say five requests all waiting for a response from the server adding another every 30 seconds. This is not ideal because:

- If the server is taking longer than 30 seconds to respond, you're adding to the loading by launching more requests. Not so important on a small scale app but when you have 1000 users it really stacks up.
- If the server does wake up after say 120 seconds then you'll get four responses all at the same time which will wreak havoc with race conditions in your app.

There's nothing particularily wrong with using setInterval (even if it is redundant with the jQuery complete callback) but you need to set a timeout.